# ec2-amazon instance can be accessed from outside avaibility zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

My instance is created by my US based friend. I am handling it from India.

Avaibility zone is - `us-west-2c`

Can it be accessed from india?

Currently when I access it from browser, it gives error `Request timed out`

IS it due to avaibility zone or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not due to an availability zone.  The availability zone has only to with where the server/resources are located.

Comment: thanks, here is my actual issue, if you can help http://serverfault.com/questions/582540/amazon-ec2-instance-gets-timed-out